# How to programmatically terminate javascript function in progress

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working in Google Sheets, I have a gs script that opens an html web form. On submit and a gs script function is executed to handle the form data. The form itself stays on the screen while the script executes (just for now..I will improve the experience with a new window and progress indicator later).

I want to allow the user to click the cancel button on the form and end the execution of the ongoing function.

I created an event listener for the "Cancel" button by using type="reset" on the cancel button and then prevented the default action. It now calls a gs script function. Inside that function I have tried "throw" and "return" and these only terminate the execution of the called function, not the ongoing script execution from the earlier "submit" action.

I need the cancel button to programmatically act like the user went to the event log and clicked "Terminate". Is this possible?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.labnol.org/code/20112-suspend-google-script-execution) work?

Comment: There is no way to replicate the "Terminate" button on https://script.google.com but you could include in your function an algorithm to check if the script should continue the execution or to interrupt it but it depends strongly in what your script does and how it does that.

Comment: The solution linked by @ObsoleteAwareProduce, for a more specific answer to your issue it would be helpful to see your code that does not terminate the script execution correctly.

Comment: @ObsoleteAwareProduce Thanks I had found that and am working with a variant of that approach for now but it is clunky and I was hoping there was a more formal way access the builtin terminate capability of the event logger

Comment: @Rubén Yes I don't think I will be able to use any watcher code with the way I am passing data around. But I will keep looking at this approach and see if I can find a way to make it work.

Comment: @ziganotschka My code is executing and terminating correctly, what I am trying to do is stop an execution that is underway and, as you indicate, it is a struggle or maybe impossible to programmatically point to a running function and issue an actual "termination" command that has the same effect of the event logger's "Terminate" menu command. I'll keep picking at it though.

Comment: Why not just let it do whatever it does and add a cancelled server function, which just modifies or adds a new entry for cancelled?

Comment: @TheMaster Do you have a link to an example of what you mean?  Right now I am handling it with a timeout based on the size of the dataset and the extent of the query.

Comment: @Dave Explain or show what your server function does.

Comment: @TheMaster The content of the code is mostly irrelevant in this case. Just create any function that calls another function. Put the second function into an infinite loop to simulate a condition a user wants to exit. Now...try to programmatically terminate the running function. Same issue. I think the answer is simply as Ruben mentions above....can't be done.

Comment: @Dave It is relevant for my comment. If your server function saves data to a Google sheet. I'm saying, let it run through. When terminate is pressed, let it just add a another row of data with the same data as above with a cancellation request. At the end of day, accept the cancellation request rows and delete the original rows. Read my previous comments: that's what I'm trying to say.  Whatever your server function does, I'm suggesting alternatives on  the server side.